# Currency sign can't be removed in CurrencyEditText in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, currency

I am using   [BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText](https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText.git) library to format edittext like currency input.  Example. if user wants to enter 10, he will simply enter 1000 and we will automatically show the value as 10.00. After I used this library, everything was going well. But, the problem is currency sign (eg.$ sign if my device's locale is US) appears at the start of EditText. I am trying to drop that sign. I have tried

> android.hint=""

like mentioned in README. But, it is not working. I know it is because of Locale. So, I tried to drop locale like below.

```
edCurrency.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ROOT);
edCurrency.setLocale(Locale.ROOT);
```

But, it is not also working. My question is how can I drop currency sign in CurrencyEditText. Any ideas or alternative ways will be appreciating!

[image]

Comment: `android:hint=""` should work. But make sure that your don't include `edCurrency.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ROOT);
edCurrency.setLocale(Locale.ROOT);`. They set locale to system default

Comment: I guess your first stop should be looking for issues raised at library repository. [Currency Visibility](https://github.com/BlacKCaT27/CurrencyEditText/issues/44)

Comment: @musooff `android:hint=""` works only for the first time. After I set some values, it automatically add $ sign at the start of EditText.

Comment: setting `setHint("")` is not an option after setting value?

Comment: ahh. sorry I was wrong. I just tested. `setHnit("")` also not working.